# Google Apps Script problem using getLinkUrl(offset)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to figure out how to use `getLinkUrl(offset)` in Google Apps Script.

I found the reference here - http://googlescriptreference.com/Document/Text/getlinkurloffset/, but I can't find any examples online.

**This GAS returns `Paragraph`in the logs**

```
var paragraph = tableCell.getChild(0);
```

**This GAS returns `the text string in the paragraph` in the logs**

```
var paragraphText = paragraph.getText();
```

**This GAS returns `NULL` in the logs**

```
var paragraphText = paragraph.getLinkUrl();
```

**This GAS returns an error ( Cannot find method getLinkUrl(number).) and  nothing in the logs**

```
var paragraphText = paragraph.getLinkUrl(2);
```

Can someone please help me understand how to use the `getLinkUrl(offset)`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was attempting to use the `getLinkUrl(offset)` directly on the paragraph element (not working example), but I needed to use `asText()` method before `getLinkUrl(offset)`.

**NOT Working**

```
var paragraphText = paragraph.getLinkUrl(2);
```

**Working**

```
var paragraphText = paragraph.asText().getLinkUrl(2);
```

**Google Document**
https://docs.google.com/document/d/136G549zIYPYBndXs70ZnR_wEFg5fPST9ZGsOlTgmDyM/edit

```
//Works if link is on a word or words instead of entire paragraph

function myFunctionP1() {
  //Find out how many Children there are
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  Logger.log(body.getNumChildren());

  //Find out which child is table
  var table = body.getChild(2); //table is child#2
  Logger.log(table);

  //Find tableCell inside of table
  var tableCell = table.getChild(0).getChild(0); //tableCell
  Logger.log(tableCell)

  //Find paragraph inside of tableCell 
  //I think, but I'm not sure, the HYPERLINK will be found somewhere within the PARAGRAPH element. But I can't figure out how to get to it.
  var paragraph = tableCell.getChild(0); //paragraph element
  Logger.log(paragraph)

  //Get paragraph text 
  var paragraphText = paragraph.asText().getLinkUrl(2); //paragraph text
  Logger.log(paragraphText)


}



//Works if link is on entire paragraph
//Works if link is on entire paragraph
//Works if link is on entire paragraph
function myFunctionP2() {
  //Find out how many Children there are
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  Logger.log(body.getNumChildren());

  //Find out which child is table
  var table = body.getChild(4); //table is child#2
  Logger.log(table);

  //Find tableCell inside of table
  var tableCell = table.getChild(0).getChild(0); //tableCell
  Logger.log(tableCell)

  //Find paragraph inside of tableCell 
  //I think, but I'm not sure, the HYPERLINK will be found somewhere within the PARAGRAPH element. But I can't figure out how to get to it.
  var paragraph = tableCell.getChild(0); //paragraph element
  Logger.log(paragraph)

  //Get paragraph text 
  var paragraphText = paragraph.getText(); //paragraph text
  Logger.log(paragraphText)

  //Get HYPERLIINK from paragraph text 
  var paragraphHYPERLINK = paragraph.getLinkUrl(); //paragraph text
  Logger.log(paragraphHYPERLINK)  

}
```

@Tanaike helped me find this solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike