# body.findText() does not return what's being searched on

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm creating a Google Apps Script that creates modular documentation. It's controlled through several tabs on a Google spreadsheet. It basically combines small source docs into a larger doc based on entries in the various sheets. Sheet `Groups` controls adding the major sections. Sheet `Tables` controls adding subsections to one of the major sections. I've got the major sections working just fine but the function controlling the subsections is failing to correctly find the subsection heading in the doc. It's finding the paragraph index of a previous section about 20 paragraphs before the searched text appears.  The problem seems to be with the line 
    `var foundTag = body.findText(sectionToUpdate);` 
it's not returning the correct location of the text in the document.

When I log `sectionToUpdate` it's the correct section heading. If I copy the text from the log an manually search the doc it does find it correctly. When I log the text from the `paragraphIndex` that's found by the search it returns the value "01" which is a table entry from the previous section.

```
function updateTablesSection(groupName) //for updating table insertion instructions
{
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var groupsSheet = app.getSheetByName("Groups");
  var tablesSheet = app.getSheetByName("Tables");
  var groupDocumentsSheet = app.getSheetByName("Group Documents");

  var sectionToUpdate = "Adding a user to ";

  sectionToUpdate = sectionToUpdate + tablesSheet.getRange(5,1).getValue();
  Logger.log(sectionToUpdate);

  var destinationDoc = getDoc(groupDocumentsSheet, groupName);
  var body = destinationDoc.getBody();
  var foundTag = body.findText(sectionToUpdate);

  if (foundTag != null) //if the section exists in the destination doc
  {
    var tagElement = foundTag.getElement();
    var parent = tagElement.getParent();
    var paragraphIndex = parent.getParent().getChildIndex(parent); //gets the section to update's paragraph index. This marks the header of the section.
    var paragraphArray = body.getParagraphs();

    Logger.log(tagElement);
    Logger.log(parent);
    Logger.log(paragraphIndex);
    Logger.log(tagElement);

    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());

    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    paragraphIndex++;
    Logger.log(paragraphArray[paragraphIndex].getText());
    Logger.log(paragraphIndex);

  }

}//end function updateTablesSection

function getDoc(sheet, name) //This function takes in a sheet and a string. returns a doc. name must be in a list in column one of the sheet. column 2 contains doc IDs
{
 var k = 2;
 var ID = "";
 var fileIterator = "";
 var url = "";              

 while(k <= sheet.getLastRow())
 {
   if (name == sheet.getRange(k, 1).getValue())
   {
    ID = sheet.getRange(k, 2).getValue();
    fileIterator = DriveApp.getFileById(ID);
    url = fileIterator.getUrl();
    return (DocumentApp.openByUrl(url));
   }
   k++;
 }
} //end function getDoc
```

And here's the logged output

```
[19-06-15 15:50:44:930 PDT] Adding a user to user_permit
[19-06-15 15:50:45:991 PDT] Text
[19-06-15 15:50:45:991 PDT] Paragraph
[19-06-15 15:50:45:991 PDT] 100.0 <-- it returns this index number
[19-06-15 15:50:45:992 PDT] Text
[19-06-15 15:50:45:992 PDT] 
[19-06-15 15:50:45:992 PDT] 01
[19-06-15 15:50:45:993 PDT] ALL
[19-06-15 15:50:45:993 PDT] -1
[19-06-15 15:50:45:994 PDT] <site number>
[19-06-15 15:50:45:994 PDT] LASTNAME.FIRSTNAME
[19-06-15 15:50:45:994 PDT] NOTE: There should be no pipes at the beginning or end of the Contact field
[19-06-15 15:50:45:995 PDT] Press Number Pad Enter to append and Number Pad * to save the row
[19-06-15 15:50:45:995 PDT] Fill in your template with the database table
[19-06-15 15:50:45:996 PDT] Adding a user to user_permit
[19-06-15 15:50:45:996 PDT] 109.0 <--this index number is where the value actually is
```

Comment: Welcome. Questions that ask for help on non-working code should include a [mcve]. The included code calls several functions like `getDoc`, `findSectionLocation`, among other, but they aren't included.

Comment: I think that in order to replicate your situation, when you provide a sample Document and the sample value of ``sectionToUpdate``, it might help users think of the issue and the solution.

Comment: The sheet just contains a list of database table names. The value in the sheet  (5,1)   is "user_permit"

Comment: @kfstrf _The problem seems to be with the line  var foundTag = body.findText(sectionToUpdate); it's not returning the correct location of the text in the document_ That's why we'd like to see the spreadsheet (or a sample non-confidential, version). We need to see the data.

Comment: @kfst Try `Logger.log(body.getChildIndex(parent.asParagraph()))`

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I can't post the whole doc but here's a screencap of the section in question. https://imgur.com/a/nIB9RaJ Also i had a sleep on it and remembered that the first section with a table had no issues. So as a test i removed the first section's table and ran it again. it now returns the expected results. this appears to have something to do with tables in the doc

Comment: The logger command "Logger.log(body.getChildIndex(parent.asParagraph()))" returns 100.0

Comment: ​I think i finally figured out why sections are not getting put in the correct location. A document is a container that contains a list of items called children. a paragraph containing only text is a child. the first line of text would have a child index of 0. the document also contains a list of paragraphs. a paragraph of text is a single paragraph and the first paragraph in a document is paragraph index of 0. As long as the document contains only text paragraphs everything works fine because the 2 numbers match up and it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: The problem comes in as soon as tables are added to the document. an entire table is 1 child of the document. that table is a container itself and has it's own children in the form of cells. if a table has 10 cells then it has 10 paragraphs. if the document has 1 paragraph of text and one table with 10 cells then it has 2 children and 11 paragraphs

Comment: See my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636525/164374